# php ss2_connect() - connect to a switch with RADIUS server

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to a CISCO switch that authenticates against a RADIUS server. This is not an industrial level switch but one for small businesses.

I have been using phpseclib for my other switches but due to some differences with the way this particular switch works, i'm looking at rolling my own solution.

I have the following basic code:

```
  <?php
  echo "attempt connect....<br>";

  Try{

        $connection = ssh2_connect('10.14.3.45', 22);
        var_dump($connection);
        echo "attemp ssh2 authorization....<br>";

       echo ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'CANNetworkInfra', 'fe8CC+ad4aA9');
       exit;
       $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'show bonjour');
       $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

       // Enable blocking for both streams
       stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
       stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

      // Whichever of the two below commands is listed first will receive its appropriate output.  The second command receives nothing
      echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
      echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errorStream);

      // Close the streams       
      fclose($errorStream);
      fclose($stream);  
     }
     catch (Exception $ex)
     {
       echo 'doing a var dump:';
        var_dump($connection);
      }
```

This code is dying with the following error message:

> Warning: ssh2_auth_password() [function.ssh2-auth-password]: Authentication failed for username using password in /var/www/test/customssh.php on line 10

I think the problem has to do with the fact that the switch is always looking for a publickey - which we are not using because we want to authenticate against a radius server.
What seems to be happening when you connect manually is this:

1. we run the following command in a terminal window: "ssh username@ipaddress"
2. the switch checks for public key in default folder of /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
3. it doesn't find the file so then the switch prompts us for username.  we type it in again.
4. then it prompts for a password.
5. after we supply the correct password, it connects.

We haven't found way to disable this check for publickeys on the switch. 
So my question is, is there any way to send the username two times via ssh2_auth_password() so we can simulate what we do manually to connect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, here's the solution to our problem.  Others may have resolved in a different way, but this seems to work for us.

What we noticed is the following about this particular series of CISCO switches (SF300)

1. popular ssh libraries like phpseclib were failing on this switch because of the limited ssh implementation.
2. php's ssh2_auth_none function returns TRUE on this switch.

What does this mean?

It seems that the ssh protocol has an authentication method called "none". This is insecure, and is usually disabled on most switches. The ssh2_auth_none() function attempts to connect without any authentication and if it fails, it returns a list of the authentication methods that the server accepts.  In the case of the SF300.. it passes and returns nothing for the authentication methods.

1. Known CLI and SSH Limitations

Although they weren't able to give us a solution, CISCO tech support did explicitly state that the small business class switches have a limited CLI and a pared down version of SSH as well so you cannot treat it as you an enterprise level switch that has a full blown ssh implementation.

In case it helps, here's a little snippet of code that shows how to connect to these types of devices:

';



         fwrite($stdio_stream, "show bonjour".PHP_EOL); //you can use \n instead of PHP_EOL but PHP_EOL is recommended.

         sleep(1);

         echo "
Results: " . stream_get_contents($stdio_stream); 

?>

Hope this helps anyone who's attempting to connect to these types of devices programmatically.